# Is there a way to call a function on multiple subviews in a view?

Tags: ios, swift, function, swiftui

I'm working on a weather app where I have subviews for each statistic ex: CurrentWeather, HourlyForecast, and DailyForecast are all separate views

and I am currently making a separate api call for each view but I know that this is very inefficient and I was wondering how I could call the func only once for everything. I have tried putting the func in a `.onAppear` on the "home screen" of my app which features all of the subviews but it doesn't seen to work as the data I need is being accessed in the subviews.

Any help would be very much appreciated as I am fairly new to SwiftUI

Here is a version of what I am basically doing right now:

```
@EnvironmentObject var data: WeatherAPI

VStack {

// Weather Condition and Temp
                
                CurrentWeather().environmentObject(WeatherAPI())
                
//Hourly Forecast
                
                HourlyModuleView()
                
//Weekly Forecast
                ForecastModuleView().environmentObject(WeatherAPI())

}.onAppear(perform: data.loadData)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove over-defines for environment objects and use one from, as I understood, `HomeScreen` view, because environment object injected into root view becomes automatically available for all subviews, like

```
@EnvironmentObject var data: WeatherAPI

...

VStack {

// Weather Condition and Temp
                
   CurrentWeather()          // << data injected automatically
                
//Hourly Forecast
                
   HourlyModuleView()        // << data injected automatically
                
//Weekly Forecast
   ForecastModuleView()      // << data injected automatically

}.onAppear(perform: data.loadData)
```

Comment: Thanks! That was a silly mistake on my part but its always helpful to have a second set of eyes to look over your code